# Simple probability question related to IT

Tags: statistics

It has been really long since I studied statistics. I'm sure for many of You it will be a basic question.

I have application test case that send request to server. It can last 180 sec.

1. What is probability that 5000 users during test case will send request in same second?
2. Assume that my application can serve 200 users. How many users can take test case (180 sec), so with probability of 80% application will work?

Comment: To tell the truth - nothing. I dont even know where to start. I can spend hours of re-learning statistics to complete this task that can be solved in 5 min by expert in this field. This is not a homework, i need to solve this problem for my work. Sorry to everyone for asking question without proper research first.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information it is not possible to answer your question. However, if you know the rate $\lambda$ users/second of user requests, then one could assume a Poisson distribution and get a reasonable answer to the questions.

I am not entirely sure whether I understand your questions correctly, so I just rephrase them.

1. What is the probability that $n=5000$ users will send requests during 180s? If your user rate per second is $\lambda$ then it is $\eta = 180\cdot \lambda$ for $180$s. Plugging that into the Poisson distribution, the probability to get $k$ users in $180$s is:
   $$P(k) = \frac{\eta^k}{k!}\, \mathrm{e}^{-\eta}$$
   If you really mean $5000$ users in the same second, then replace $\eta$ by $\lambda$.
2. I interpret your second question as: What is the rate of users I can allow such that with probability $80\%$ there won't be more than $n=200$ users in $180$s? This can be written in terms of the cumulative distribution function of the Poisson distribution
   $$P_\eta(k\le n) = \frac{\Gamma(n+1,\eta)}{n!}\ge 0.8.$$
   $\Gamma$ denotes the incomplete Gamma-function. Now, I don't know how to solve that analytically. The simplest way might just be to try out several values of $\eta$ and take the largest one that still fulfills the requirement.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I need to dig into it. For clarification during test case there is only one request. The test starts, users have 180 sec to finish it and they will send one request.

Comment: Yes, but as I understand it you don't want to many other users sending requests during that time.

Comment: This is a bit more complicated. My client what application to run with 5000 users simultaneously but have really bad internet bandwith - to serve 200 users/sec. I want to prove him that
1. probability that 5000 users hit request at the same time during 3 min test case is very small (i think)
2. probability that 250 users from 5000 users will hit request at same time during 3 min test case is quite big (i think)

Comment: In case there are maximally 5000 users, a Binomial distribution might be more appropriate. However, since the request rate is probably low and the number of users is high, the Poisson distribution will probably do. But the problem remains: You need to know or assume the rate of requests.